# Representation theory over any field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

I understand that representation theory of complex reductive groups is essentially combinatorial. By general principles, I imagine Galois theory then determines the theory over any field. For example, over a separably closed field, it works exactly the same way as over the complex numbers. Is that an accurate summary? Is there a reference where this exercise is worked out?

Comment: I think that everything is fine over a characteristic-0, algebraically closed field, but that there might be problems like the failure of complete reductivity in positive characteristic.  (Also, standard reductions to the reductive case, by taking the quotient by the unipotent radical, can fail in the separably but not algebraically closed setting.  I'm not sure if that causes representation-theoretic problems.)

Comment: I think this is the first time I have heard the term "any field" used for such a specific collection of fields.

Comment: LSpice is completely correct.  There are almost no **linearly** reductive (smooth, connected) groups in positive characteristic: only the tori.

Comment: In case @JasonStarr's terminology is unfamiliar, note that, confusing as it is, a linear algebraic group that is reductive need not be linearly reductive; the latter condition is, by definition, essentially what you want.  See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Reductive_group (where is also defined geometric reductivity; fortunately Haboush showed reductivity *is* geometric reductivity).  The historical reason for the confusing terminology is that, in characteristic 0, reductivity is also equivalent to linear reductivity, by Weyl.

Comment: I thought that I had a vague picture of the situation (characteristic 0:  like you'd expect; positive characteristic:  fuhgeddaboutit), but @JasonStarr's comments ([especially](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277920/representation-theory-over-any-field#comment684858_277921)) and @‍FriedrichKnop's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/277941) have shown me that there's a lot more to it than I thought.  Thanks for asking this question!

Comment: In the complex case, do you refer to unitary representations? finite-dimensional representations?

Comment: As YCor's question suggests, there is a huge difference when infinite dimensional representations are permitted, which I guess is not what the OP has in mind here.   "Combinatorics" as for Lie algebras in Fulton-Harris usually requires finite dimensionality.   Then the highest weight classification of irreducibles is possible, though in prime characteristic little else is known in general.

Answer (score 8):

As already mentioned, the representation theory of a reductive depends heavily on the characteristic of the ground field. In particular, in positive characteristic it is of a very non-combinatorial nature.

Nevertheless, the determinantion of the *irreducible* representations is quite uniform over all characteristics. In this case, Galois theory can be used to determine irreducible representations over any field. For connected reductive groups, this "exercise", as you call it, has been worked out by Tits in his paper

Tits, J. Représentations linéaires irréductibles d'un groupe réductif sur un corps quelconque. J. Reine Angew. Math. **247** (1971) 196–220.

He even considers irreducible representations over division fields. This exercise is much less trivial than it sounds since it involves, at a minimum, the classification of reductive groups over any field. At the end, the results are very pretty, though. Apart form highest weight theory they involve a homomorphism from the character group of the center of the group $G$ to the Brauer group of the ground field $k$.

Comment: I suppose this depends on what one means by "determination". We have a nice description of the irreducibles, but we don't even know their dimensions.

Comment: Is there an english reference where the exposition from the Tit's article is written/summarized ? I guess there must be one.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. There are a few things to check, but the theory that you find in standard sources, such as in Fulton and Harris, do go through for separably closed fields as well.

Comment: No.  Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.  Consider the standard action of $\textbf{SL}_{n,k}$ on the vector space $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_1$ of linear polynomials.  There is an induced action of $\textbf{SL}_{n,k}$ on the vector space $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_p$ of homogeneous degree $p$ polynomials.  In characteristic $0$, this action is irreducible.  However, the subspace spanned by $x_1^p,\dots,x_n^p$ is $\textbf{SL}_{n,k}$-invariant.  This is roughly the reason that the only linearly reductive (smooth, connected) groups in positive characteristic are tori.

Comment: One more point: the representation theory in Fulton-Harris is representation theory of Lie algebras rather than representation theory of reductive groups.  In characteristic $0$, for a simply connected, semisimple group, the irreducible representations are the same as for the Lie algebra.  In positive characteristic, representation theory of Lie algebras is even more wild than representation theory of reductive groups.  This is the reason for "reduced Lie algebras" and "reduced representations", cf. http://home.math.au.dk/jantzen/tokio.pdf

Comment: Typo correction: "reduced Lie algebra" --> "restricted Lie algebra", "reduced representations" --> "restricted representations".

Comment: @JasonStarr In characteristic $0$, the *finite dimensional* representations are the same. In general, the Lie algebra will have many more infinite dimensional ones.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft.  Yes, you are correct.  I should have specified that I was considering finite dimensional representations.  Thank you.